# Pegar valores com jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um seguinte campo,

```
 <input name="dados[<?= $i ?>][quantidade]" class="quantidade" type="text" value="<?= isset($dados['quantidade']) ? $dados['quantidade'] : '' ?>" id="quantidade"/>
```

E tenho um modal que quando eu escolho um alimento novo, ele adiciona outro campo como o de cima, tenho que pegar esses valores com jQuery e realizar uma soma, como e que faço para pegar todos esses campos?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode obter usando o [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
var soma = 0;

$('.quantidade').each(function(index) {
    soma += parseInt($(this).val());
});

alert('Soma: ' + soma);
```

Vejo que você está utilizando o mesmo ID `quantidade` para todos os elementos, isto é errado, cada elemento deve possuir uma identificação única.

Espero que ajude!